# Aerobatics in "firm" IMC -- how would one do it?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, flight-planning, aerobatics

Assuming you are aerobatically trained, IFR rated, have an aircraft that is rated for the aerobatic maneuvers you are planning to perform (let us assume that it is acrobatic category, even), and the aircraft in question is type certified and equipped for flight under IFR, how would you plan out and safely execute a set of aerobatic maneuvers in IMC (think solid cloud, but without serious up/downdrafts, icing, or lightning hazards) while flying under IFR?  Can you define a "box clearance" in an IFR flight plan, akin to a VFR aerobatic box, only defined by coordinates or intersections instead of ground reference points?  How feasible is it to carry out the Aresti catalog maneuvers by reference to flight instruments alone?

Comment: You can indeed ask for a block altitude and your clearance would be "block 14,000 to 16,000."

Comment: @rbp -- block altitudes I know about, but for acro in IMC, I'd want positive *horizontal* separation as well, which is why I asked about the "box clearance" -- the two would be used together to get a protected airspace volume to operate in.

Comment: Wave boxes in Class A airspace for gliders are defined via LOAs. Not sure you could get an IFR Acro box.

Comment: Wave box loa: http://www.seattleglidercouncil.org/SeattleGliderrev2003.pdf and http://www.seattleglidercouncil.org/gliderareamaps2009.pdf

Comment: I am interested to learn the answer to this question from someone with more aerobatic experience than me.  The ten or so hours of aerobatics that I've done have convinced me that attempting it without outside visual reference is *not* a feat I'd like to attempt.

Comment: What's the point of aerobatics if nobody can see you?

Comment: @raptortech97 -- I was thinking of this as something of  an "instrument mastery" exercise for an aerobatic pilot, if you will...

Comment: You could get a sector clearance. aka, you'd be cleared to operate between the ABC VOR's 090 to 140 radials from 50 to 80 DME, block altitude 4000 to 8000 or whatever you'd want to try.

Comment: I've heard at least one story of a fatality resulting from an attempt to loop in cloud, involved a P-38 during WW2 training.

Comment: When I was a student Naval Aviator in the TA-4J Skyhawk we would do a full acro series under the hood as a confidence maneuver.  (loop, aileron roll, barrel roll, half cuban eight, immelmann, and split S)

Comment: @MichaelHall -- you should expand on that, it sounds like answer material to me

Comment: It was done in VMC in a MOA, so I don't think it directly addresses the question.

Answer (score 8):

No - you don't do it.

First and obvious reason, there's no body to see it.

Perhaps much more important is safety though. When pulling a loop, it's not like flight simulator where you just yank the stick aft and watch the attitude indicator (AI). An aerobatic pilot is constantly checking his attitude by looking at his wing tips, quickly glancing the left and right sides back and forth.

In fact, the AI is usually caged (meaning it is locked to prevent rotation) in such violent maneuver. The proper procedure is cage the AI, perform the maneuver, check straight and level (*visually*), then uncage the AI. If you don't, the gyroscope will tumble quite some time before it settles again, rendering it useless. Meaning, if you perform in IMC, you won't have accurate AI information for recovery.

For nearly vertical maneuvers (e.g. stall turn, rolling while vertical), even a functioning AI wouldn't help, since horizontal direction is undefined in this state. The AI and compass will just flip, yet you have no way to determine which way you go.

Violent G-forces also mean it is much more difficult to read instruments during such maneuver.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this if you had an attitude reference instrument that didn't need to be caged?

Comment: I guess fighter jets have it. I've never flown one though!

Comment: @kevin: I would expect most glass cockpits not to need caging as these use a set of (vibrating or laser) rate gyros and computer integration rather than free spinning gyro. Though apparently not all software is certified for it.

Comment: Aside: Look up gimbal lock on Apollo 11/13.

Comment: @JanHudec these guys had glass cockpit http://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=20100214-0

Comment: @VladimirF, the fact that your AI works does not mean you are not going to loose spatial orientation and that extract does not say their AI tumbled.

Comment: @JanHudec I haven't said anything you are disproving. I pointed out that a glass cockpit does not save you.

Comment: @VladimirF, nothing can save you if you don't know what you are doing. But that is totally irrelevant here; the only question here is whether it provides correct attitude information when inverted or not.

Comment: @JanHudec In the linked full report you can read that according to the manufacturer, it will indicate correctly during a roll, but not during a loop. Or as kevin says when rolling when nearly vertical.

Comment: @VladimirF, hm, that's interesting. It also makes some sense; roll is definitely possible, but loop most likely isn't (the plane would likely stall or overspeed, depending on direction, before completing the loop at the maximum permitted G).

Comment: I've heard of at least one accident caused by a pilot trying to fly aerobatics in cloud.